# Defining Lie groups without the notion of a manifold

Tags: lie-groups

I like to introduce (matrix) Lie groups without the notion of manifolds. 
(And I am happy to sacrify the "few" Lie groups which are not matrix groups
in favor of a simpler definition.)

I was thinking of the following definition:

- $G$ is a (matrix) Lie groups $:\Leftrightarrow$ $G$ is a closed subgroups of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$.

(I do not care about Lie groups over finit fields either...)

This definition seems to be okay for my purpose but it requires to equip $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ with a metric (to give closeness a meaning). My question:

Am I correct: If I do not want to use the notion of a manifold (or a non-standard replacement with similar complexity), I need to equip $GL(n,\mathbb{R}$ with a metric to sufficiently characterize matrix Lie groups?

Comment: Why did you ask this again? You can edit your question.

Comment: Hi Tobias, my previous question was slightly different. I deleted it since I just found the answer to it once I submitted it. Sorry for the confusion, I know how to edit ;-)

Comment: Anyway, you only need a topology, not a metric to get the closed subsets. And there is certainly no way to avoid topological questions when dealing with Lie groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the approach given in Hall's book on Lie groups where he defines a matrix Lie group to be a closed subgroup of $\text{GL}_n(\Bbb{C})$. Of course when we mean closed  it is with respect to the usual Euclidean topology on $\Bbb{C}^{n^2}$.

You may choose not to equip $\text{GL}_n(\Bbb{C})$ with a metric but I think ultimately at the end of the day you want to equip it with at least some kind of *topology*. From my experience the usual topology on these groups is the one induced from the Euclidean metric.

Comment: Chapter $0$ of Knopp's book _Lie Groups Beyond an Introduction_ is another source for defining matrix Lie groups from scratch.

Comment: Whoops, I meant Knapp, not Knopp.